# Where should custom devise views go?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a custom controller in `app/controllers/devise/member_registration_controller.rb` that looks like this:

```
class Devise::MemberRegistrationController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def create
  ....
  end

end
```

And I put my custom devise views in:

```
app/views/devise/member_registration/
```

I have

```
config.scoped_views = true
```

in my `devise.rb` file

My `routes.rb` has:

```
devise_for :members, :controllers => {
  :registrations => 'devise/members_registration'
}
```

But I'm still seeing this in the server log when I view the page:

```
Rendered /Users/gerry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/devise-3.0.3/app/views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb within layouts/application
```

Am I missing something? I'm using Rails 4 and Devise 3.0.3

Comment: did you try `rails g devise:views` and checck all the views are created or not?

Comment: `devise_for :members, :controllers => {
  :registrations => members_registration'
}`  and `views/members_registration/edit.html.erb`

Answer (score 0):

For own controller view you can try below one

```
 devise_for :members, :controllers => { :registrations => members_registration' }
```

and

```
views/members_registration/edit.html.erb
```

in controller

```
 class MemberRegistrationController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  ...
 end
```